# Exporting camera crane alembic

Tags: animation, export, camera, alembic

I'm using blender's crane camera rig to get a shot however I need to export the camera to an external program but because the camera is being controlled by the crane it doesn't have any transform information itself. Is it at all possible to export this camera with it's motion while using this rig?

Thanks,
Mitchell

Answer (score 0):

Didn't take long to find the solution. You just have to select the rig itself and export that as an alembic. Rather than doing what I was doing and selecting the camera.